# Can I incorporate a stored procedure into a regular query or am I thinking about it wrong? (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

This may be a classic SO scenario where the question doesn't address what I'm trying to achieve so I'll just explain my situation.

I have created a large number of SSRS reports. Many of which share a number of common fields. On a pretty regular basis the underlying definitions of these fields changes and I have to go through each report making the requisite changes which is time consuming and opens up the possibility of errors making the reports diverge.

I have created a procedure that takes @startdate and @enddate as parameters and returns 4 of the common fields as per our current definitions (Calls offered, calls answered, answered in 20s, ring offs) which works great when I execute it on it's own. What I want is to have that procedure as part of a larger SELECT query which has non common fields in it. Something like

```
SELECT

,[Date]
,[Total seconds]
,(procedure fields)
,...

from [table]

where [date] >= '2017-01-01'

group by [date]
```

In my thinking, this would mean that when the definitions change I'd only have to alter the procedure once and every report will update. Is this possible? Or am I using the wrong tool for what I'm trying to achieve? and if so what should I be using instead?

Comment: Well even if you change the SP definition, your reports will not show the newly added column until you change the report design, you will need to change/update the report too, to show the new columns. OR create reports with dynamic columns. and only then if you change the proc the report will change too but to use dynamic columns in SSRS reports there is whole another and more sleek way of handling it. Using SQL Server tables to store report column names etc.

Comment: I want to keep the columns in the SP the same but change how they are defined. For example the definition of a ring off is a large case statement with different aspects for different accounts some only "count" if callers ring off after 5 second some after 10 etc. As new accounts come online or old account change the definition of what constitutes a "ring off" will change.

Comment: So you mean, the output of the columns is the same (Name, number & Data types), its only the logic for rows that changes ?

Comment: Yes, see my edited comment above for clarification (hopefully).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I get your problem, but it's possible that views to combine the common fields are the thing you're looking for instead of using stored procedures. And views can integrate directly into queries as tables would whereas with stored procedures, you'd have to do additional things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think an Inline table valued function is a better candidate for your requirement.

You will be able to push down the predicate using inline-table valued function and also you can select from it in your select statements.

Something like.....

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ILTVF_CommonColumns ( 
    @startdate  DATETIME 
,   @enddate    DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT    Column1   
            , Column2
            , Column3
            , Column4
    FROM    dbo.TableName             -- Change logic here whenever need to
    WHERE   DateColumn >= @startdate
    AND     DateColumn <= @enddate;
GO
```

**Sample Select**

```
SELECT
            [Date]
        ,   [Total seconds]
        ,   fn.*
from [table] t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.ILTVF_CommonColumns (@StartDate , @EndDate) fn 
                                            ^           ^
                                            |___________| 
                                        Or these could be fields from your [Table]
where t.[date] >= '2017-01-01'
group by [date]
```